# Getting deeper into map (Occupancy Grid)

Tags: navigation, mapping, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm developing a navigation algorithm, for which I need to find out corners and walls present in the room.
I've been playing around with turtlebot simulation. I've made a very simple rectangular room of about 3.0 x 2.4 meter square.
I've saved the map I generated using gmapping.

To find the corners and walls, I'm writing my own python script, using OpenCV functions like Harris Corner detection and Contours, and Canny. I'll be feeding the map.pgm file to do the same. I'll receive the pixels with corners and wall.

Now, I need to know where these are in relation to the bot. That's where the problem is.

**I am not able to understand where does the map set its origin?**

**And if it's the same for every map file?**

**Does the robot's start, end pose or trajectory during the gmapping affect the map origin?**

**Also, if the map isn't at the top left corner, then how can I compute the distance between that pixel and my robot?**
I'd thought of identifying the pixel, then knowing its location with respect to map, and map's origin with respect to base_footprint. That way I'd know the vector joining the pixel and the base_footprint, and can drive to the point if I want to. I'm using the default 0.05 resolution, therefore each pixel should be 5 cm.

According to my observations, the map origin depends on the start pose of the robot while the mapping process. But if someone experienced can answer these questions, it would be a great help.

**Also, if you think this isn't a good approach, and have a better approach, please teach me, or let me know. Thanks!**

As per following images, map origin isn't same, and not necessarily at the top left.
Map 1:

[image: image description]

Map 2:

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337215/getting-deeper-into-map-(occupancy-grid)/) by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on ROS Answers with karma: 463 on 2019-11-09

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2019-11-09**:
I read about nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid and nav_msgs/MapMetaData. So the /map will have cell values (-1, 0 or 100) and that MapMetaData is a part of OccupancyGrid message, and holds info like height, width, resolution and origin. Can I use the origin data to calculate the cell value of the map origin, and therefore to calculate its distance from any pixel of interest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi parzival,

> I am not able to understand where does
> the map set its origin?

The origin of the map is defined in its .yaml file, its value depends on how it's created, but it usually when using gmapping it is given by the width and height of the map and its resolution, so as to try to put the 0,0 position at the center of the map.  Although this is by no means a rule, it depends on a variety of things.

> And if it's the same for every map
> file?

No, it depends on the map, moreover, it can be changed on the .yaml file

> Does the robot's start, end pose or
> trajectory during the gmapping affect
> the map origin?

Not really, it only affects the position of the robot on the map

> Also, if the map isn't at the top left
> corner, then how can I compute the
> distance between that pixel and my
> robot?

You need to put both things on the same reference frame, you can extract the position of a given pixel on the /map reference using a simple computation, an example can be

```
void mapToWorld(unsigned int map_x, unsigned int map_y, double& pos_x, double& pos_y, nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid map)
{
    pos_x = map.info.origin.position.x + (map_x + 0.5) * map.info.resolution;
    pos_y = map.info.origin.position.y + (map_y + 0.5) * map.info.resolution;
}
```

Then you can easily get the distance to the robot's position on the map.

---

Originally posted by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) with karma: 802 on 2019-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5